# Adobe Livecycle - ps to pdf smoke script - is there a one-liner?

Tags: livecycle

Have never seen/used Adobe LiveCycle but have been asked to provide a smoke test for the installation - specifically to provide a script that will pick up a postscript file from the local drive and convert it to a pdf.

What is the simplest way to do this using LiveCycle and from the machine on which LiveCycle is installed?

I see from a search on the internet there is support for CLI and JavaScript but I would appreciate it if someone could at least point me in the right direction as there is quite a lot of reading to do and I need to produce the script yesterday actually.

I found this link which shows how to do it via a [web service and java](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/ProgramLC/WS624e3cba99b79e12-726e92b21336a3542ad-8000.2.html#WS624e3cba99b79e12e69a9941333732bac8-77a5.2)  using API's but there is quite a lot of prep/effort and the config isn't really viable in this scenario:

Many thanks in advance for any guidance on this.

Regards

Kevin

Comment: What is your programming/scripting language choice? Also do you need to provide a script or would any LiveCycle solution do, such as a process with watched folders?

Comment: No preference. Its the least amount of effort to test the conversion. I know the deployment package includes a test PS file to be used and currently the LC UI can provide the test against the file but all deployments are highly automated but human interaction needs to be swapped out by creating/including relevant files in the deployment package that can be used in the automatic execution of a test.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight-forward one liner script to perform what you want. Unless you can manage to implement a web-service call to the distiller service using CURL.

You can use Java/Groovy to use the EJB endpoint, or any language to use the SOAP endpoint to invoke the distiller service.

Alternatively you you can configure the DistillerService in LiveCycle Admin UI (Home > Services > Applications and Services > Service Management > Configure DistillerService) to have a watched folder endpoint. This would automatically pickup files from a folder, convert them to PDF.

[image]

You can also automate watch folder configuration as explained [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=001174.html).